# Hbase: How does reading of compressed data work?

Tags: hadoop, compression, hbase, snappy

I understand that if we enable compression for column family then the values of hfiles saved will be compressed using the algorithm we specify and compression happens at block level.

But when reading the data block out how does this decompression work. For eg. If we use snappy how does the read happen. How does it figure out how to read a specific key value from the compressed data? How is this done in a real time basis.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in an answer? Compression doesn't prevent it from being read, and it's not a property unique to hbase, e.g. Spark can read snappy compressed Parquet data... Mapreduce can read Bzip2 compressed archives. Sure, there's overhead, but it's not significant

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm looking at how the decompression procedure works on the fly. At what point decompression happens and where does this happen?

Comment: It happens at query time by the HDFS client. Either the compressed file is downloaded to the client, then extracted, or it's extracted to temp hdfs location, I'm not really sure

Comment: @OneCricketeer I went through the documentation but there was nothing I could find regarding this.

Comment: I don't think the documentation is unique to Hadoop/Hbase. You'll need to look at Snappy Java library documentation, similar to linked below

Answer (score 1):

The data is decompressed in memory 'on the fly' and the value is then read in uncompressed format.  This is done quickly as using cpu to uncompress is faster than doing large reads from file.

The decompression happens while the [file is being read from disk](https://github.com/electrum/hadoop-snappy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/SnappyCodec.java).

Comment: At what point decompression happens and where does this happen on the fly?

Comment: I added a reference to the code in the question so you can explore "how" at your leisure.

Comment: Why is it important to know this is there a problem you are facing that is related?

Comment: Apart from looking throigh code there is nothing in doc right. I couldn't find anything

Comment: I'm not aware of a documented process.  If you found the answer helpful please upvote it.  If you think it is the answer and your comfortable marking it as correct that would be appreciated.